# Remember last selected items per page in global search

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, global-search

The "items per page" stat is being remembered permanently (cross device, attached to our account, not via a cookie) in the search results of any site.

However, in the [global search on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search), this stat is being reset whenever searching again; choosing the items per page affects only that single search:

> [image: items per page affecting only single search]

I assume this is because stackexchange.com is not attached to an ordinary account behind the scenes, so can't use the same server side cache. This can be bypassed by using a different cache probably, or by using the network profile if possible.

Can it be done/fixed?

Comment: it's worse than that; it doesn't even remember it between *pages of the same search*

Comment: Also, after doing "next page" several times, selecting a different page size sets the page index back to 1.

Comment: Additional details here: [“Search all Sites” UI is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321814/222992)

Comment: @DaveTweed to be honest resetting the page index after changing page size is expected.