# "Search all Sites" UI is broken

Tags: bug, search, user-interface

I was just using the "Search all Sites" feature (https://stackexchange.com/search?q=cryptocurrency), and there seem to be several problems with the UI. (I'm using Ubuntu 16.02 + Firefox 64.0 at the moment, but it also fails in the same way on Windows 7 + Chrome 71.0.)

The options at the bottom don't work:

- It seems to default to 30 results per page. If I select 50, then "next page", it reverts back to 30.
- If I "next page" a couple of times, and then select 50 again, it reverts back to page 1.

Obviously, these "state changes" are not being propagated correctly from page to page.

It all works correctly in a site-specific search (e.g., StackOverflow). I note that the style of the controls is different here, so it's probably a different set of code.

This expands on the existing question [Remember last selected items per page in global search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310655) (which doesn't have an answer) by pointing out that changing the page size also resets the page index. That one should probably be made a duplicate of this one.